# Add firewall-cmd service permanently

Tags: redhat, firewall-cmd

On RHEL 7, I am trying to add service `postgresql` permanently.

Without --permanent option, the command below runs well.

```
[root@sample services]# firewall-cmd --list-services
dhcpv6-client http https ssh
[root@sample services]# firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql
success
[root@sample services]# firewall-cmd --list-services
dhcpv6-client http https postgresql ssh
[root@sample services]#
```

However, when using --permanent option, below error surfaces.

```
[root@sample services]# firewall-cmd --remove-service=postgresql
success
[root@sample services]# firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql --permanent
Error: INVALID_SERVICE: oracle
```

Why is the error mentioning 'oracle'? How do I actually allow 'postgresql' service permanently via firewall-cmd?

Comment: I agree that you should do what is advised in the linked Q&A.